# node.js juice not removing all <style> tags

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to remove all `<style>` from an HTML using [juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) 9.1.0, but juice is keeping some out.

If I paste the HTML on [the demo website](https://automattic.github.io/juice/) it removes all `<style>`.

I'm using the following test code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const juice = require('juice');

const rawHtml = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
}
a:active {
  color: #000 !important;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00c8b4 !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table[class="body"] img {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test!!!
  </body>
  </html>
`;

const juiceHtml = juice(rawHtml)
console.log(juiceHtml)

/*

OUTPUT:

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
}
a:active {
  color: #000 !important;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00c8b4 !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table[class="body"] img {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test!!!
  </body>
  </html>


*/
```

Sample RunKit https://runkit.com/embed/fjqdnm3ckkdv (change the output from Rendered HTML to Full Text)

I tried the same options as on the demo website, but still, it did not work. The most important option is `removeStyleTags`, but that's `true` by default.

```
// removeStyleTags is true by default
const juiceHtml = juice(rawHtml, { removeStyleTags: true }) 

// exactly as the demo website
const juiceHtml = juice(rawHtml, {
  applyStyleTags: true,
  removeStyleTags: true,
  preserveMediaQueries: true,
  preserveFontFaces: true,
  applyWidthAttributes: true,
  applyHeightAttributes: true,
  applyAttributesTableElements: true,
  inlinePseudoElements: false,
  xmlMode: false,
  preserveImportant: false
})
```

None of this worked.

Comment: As is super clear on the demo site from all the checkboxes, that's a config option, so: set that same option in your own code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, I did try all the options as in the demo. But no luck. The most important option is `removeStyleTags`which is true by default. Still, it did not work with the exact same default options. Any ideas on what else it could be? 

Comment: Then remember to update your post, because nowhere in your code do you set the juice options right now.

Comment: Sure thing. I added an EDIT. The most important one is removeStyleTags, but that's true by default.

Comment: Don't use "EDIT: ...", that's for answers that need to be changed years after the fact because things changed so much the answer is now different. For posts, just work the information in as part of "one post".

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's all very helpful. I've also added a RunKit reference. I hope this also helps to clarify to issue. "Sample RunKit https://runkit.com/embed/fjqdnm3ckkdv (change the output from Rendered HTML to Full Text)"

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to put the link to the issue you filed in your post (btw: nice! far too many folks don't bother to actually let the people who _need_ to know, know).

Comment: This is a hard one, possibly a bug in the `juice` package. Have been able to re-produce but not fix your issue.

Comment: My suspicion is that some of the dependencies have changed that are not reflected by the nodejs package. I.e. the web version is using different dependencies.

Comment: I think I've found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Apparently, the webversion of juice uses an extremely outdated version which gives a different behaviour because a different CSS parser is used.

---

My initial suspicion was that some dependencies are different in the web and nodejs version.

I was able to confirm this by looking at the source code of the web-version and the nodejs-version:

Source of the web-version:

```js
exports.getPreservedText = function(css, options) {
  var rules = cssom.parse(css).cssRules || [];

  // ...
}
```

Source of latest version of the nodejs package:

```js
exports.getPreservedText = function(css, options, ignoredPseudos) {
  var parsed = mensch.parse(css, {position: true, comments: true});

  // ...
}
```

You can see that the latest nodejs version uses a package called `mensch` while the web-version uses a package called `cssom`.

Its also clear from the function signature that the "web-version" uses a **different** version of the juice package.

Digging through the source code of the [`juice`](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) package it seems that the web-version is using an *extremely* old version [`2.0.0`](https://github.com/Automattic/juice/blob/v2.0.0/lib/utils.js#L102).

You can confirm this yourself by comparing the file `lib/utils.js` from version [`3.0.0`](https://github.com/Automattic/juice/blob/v3.0.0/lib/utils.js#L90) (which is the first version to use `mensch` instead of `cssom`) and version [`2.0.0`](https://github.com/Automattic/juice/blob/v2.0.0/lib/utils.js#L102).

Installing the outdated version `2.0.0` like this:

`npm install --save juice@2`

fixes (i.e. gives the same behaviour as in web) the problem.

I would open a bug report on their repository, saying that their online demo uses an outdated and possibly broken version of juice.

Comment: this is such a great answer and investigation. Thank you! It seems I need to go back to version 1.0.0 to really get this working. https://runkit.com/64cbc45de6a81f000872f294/64cc0dc37589620008bafdd6 with version 2.0.0 keeps the media queries. But then I get concerned with such an older version ‍♂️

I opened a bug report. I'm just surprised this is not working, it seems a popular project, and this seems an obvious issue based on what the project is meant for.

Comment: @PabloCantero You're most welcome! I agree that using an older version is certainly not the best idea. I'm surprised as well, that there seems to be a big regression in their code base. Would you be so kind to include the link to the bug report you filed? For future readers.

Comment: Sure thing! https://github.com/Automattic/juice/issues/470

Comment: For future readers - I landed on [css-inline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-inline) which worked like I expected